# three js merged geometry vertices

Tags: javascript, three.js, webgl, csg

`const wallGeometry = new THREE1.BoxGeometry(0.2, 5, 2); const wallMaterial = new THREE1.MeshStandardMaterial({ color: 0x00ff00 }); const wallMesh = new THREE1.Mesh(wallGeometry, wallMaterial); const windowGeometry = new THREE1.BoxGeometry(2, 5, 0.2); const windowMaterial = new THREE1.MeshStandardMaterial({ color: 0x00ff00, side: THREE1.DoubleSide }); const windowMesh = new THREE1.Mesh(windowGeometry, windowMaterial); const windowCSG = CSG.fromMesh(windowMesh); const resultCSG = windowCSG.subtract(wallCSG);`

I want to transfer the corner points of the resultCSG geometry formed at the end of this code to an array.
code and version of library

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow. Please read [How to ask Questions](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and provide [Minimal Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).